# Alternately sending questions to aiogram

Tags: python, aiogram

I am developing a bot that sends a test
My problem is that I pull out all 10 questions from the database
and when looping, the bot sends all the questions in one go
I need the bot to send one question, and if the user chooses an option, another question is sent, and so on up to question 10
I am writing a bot on aiogram

here is the code that throws everything at once

```
    for i in quest:
        if len(i['img']) >= 1:
            await call.message.answer_photo(photo=open(f'backends/{i["img"]}', 'rb'), caption=f'{i["question"]}',
                                            reply_markup=markup)
        elif len(i['video_gif']) >= 1:
            await call.message.answer_video(video=open(f'backends/{i["video_gif"]}', 'rb'),
                                            caption=f'{i["question"]}', reply_markup=markup)
        else:
            await call.message.answer(text=f'{i["question"]}', reply_markup=markup)

        await Quest.answer.set()
```

Comment: Where is your code that does this? Please include it in your post.

Comment: @wkl hat's just the point that I can't think of writing such code

Comment: `My problem is that I pull out all 10 questions from the database and when looping, the bot sends all the questions in one go` - this implies you've written code, but it _doesn't work_. Please show the broken code you already have and that will allow people to debug or point out what you're doing wrong.